# Insert two sub reports and show at once

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report and have some data in details a, and I added two sub reports in details b and details c respectively.
I want to show details a whole data first then details b whole data and details c whole data but report show 1st row of details a then all records of details b and then details c and then 2nd row and again all records of details b and details c and so on.
I tried to insert sub reports on report footer but that show no data.
what to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted these two sub reports in report footer and got the result.

Answer (score 1):

It is the functionality of crystal reports where it is processing the all detail sections at once. I have 2 solution:

1. Try creating another subreport for details a.
2. Second you tried already placing all sub reports in report footer, I would suggest you to check the sub reports once why those are not displaying any data in report footer.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you union all three queries, add one extra column to all the union queries. Hard code that column with 1 for detail a query, 2 for detail b query and 3 for detail c query. then do order by hard coded value column.